# Facebook Login On Xamarin Forms After Embedded Webviews Have been Deprecated

Tags: facebook, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am struggling to login on Xamarin Forms with Facebook on android specifically, ios is. still working, the implementation in my app is as described in this article: https://evgenyzborovsky.com/2018/03/09/using-native-facebook-login-button-in-xamarin-forms/ and has worked perfectly until Facebooks changes. Now when users try to login we get the following error message on android only: "Login disabled", "For your account security, logging in to Facebook from an embedded browser is disabled. You may be able to continue by updating the app you're logging in from and trying again."

I have read the write up on Facebook Developers here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/deprecating-webviews

But the solution does not seem to be clear for Xamarin Forms as we are using Xamarin.Facebook.Android version 7.1.0

Any help or being pointed in the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The package has been updated few days ago to the version 11.2.0.1.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Facebook.Android/11.2.0.1

I had the exact same issue and it's now fixed.